# Forty-Eight: What is the next bigger number?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

How to solve this puzzle? Please explain with steps please! 
[image: Follow the link]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The magic word is

> Pell equation: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)

What the puzzle actually does is: The smaller square $x^2=25$ equals $\frac{1}{2}48+1$, and the larger square $y^2=49$ equals $48+1$. By multiplying the first equation by $2$ and then subtracting the second from it we get the (negative) Pell equation

> $2x^2-y^2=1$

The solutions of this Pell equation are given by the following sequence $(x_n,y_n)$:

> $x_1=1$ and $y_1=1$
>   $x_{n+1}=3x_n+2y_n$ and $y_{n+1}=4x_n+3y_n$

Here $(x_2,y_2)=(5,7)$ corresponds to the given solution, 
and $(x_3,y_3)=(29,41)$ corresponds to the solution you are looking for.
The corresponding magic number and

> the answer to the puzzle is:  **1680**

with $x_3^2=\frac{1}{2}1680+1$ and $y_3^2=1680+1$.

The answer can also be found in the **"The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences"**, as sequence [A008845](http://oeis.org/A008845).
The next five terms (and magic numbers) are $57120$, $1940448$, $65918160$, $2239277040$, and $76069501248$.

Answer (score 4):

The smallest i could get was $1680$. ($1681=41^2$,$841=29^2$).